# how to synchronize between a server svn and site in production

Tags: apache, svn, synchronization, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I wonder how I can add the synchronization between a server and svn production site in the same server
I administer the areas under plesk panel
now the svn server when you walk but I am a developer commits a file will be place in the folder httpdocs Site
I am doing some research on this I find it necessary to add the post-commit file will be called after each commit
I put this line in the file but nothing thus
/usr/bin/svn update /var/www/vhosts/monsite.com/httpdocs/ --username --password 
and I receive this response
Skipped '/var/www/vhosts/monsite.com/httpdocs'
thank you

Answer (score 0):

/var/www/vhosts/monsite.com/httpdocs/ must be Working Copy, created with `svn co <URL-OF-REPO>`

Comment: Hello
thank you for your response
but I must add or execute this command or
thank you very much